# How can i set an autoincrement to tinyint field in sql server compact?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, ef-database-first

I want to set a **tinyint** field as autoincrement, but table constructor dont let me do it. But he lets to **int** and **bigint** types. Whats the problem?

Here is the screenshot: http://gyazo.com/ce8d345ee94bf26e833fe16133b5eee5.png

The first row "Идентификация" is an **Identity** field in English.

Comment: If, as you indicate, this table is only ever going to contain 40 rows, why not just assign the ID values manually?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Compact only support int and bigint with IDENTITY

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you use TinyInt? TinyInt has a range from -128 to +127, so is is not very well suited for auto_increment columns.

Comment: TinyInt has a storage of 1 byte, so [0, 255] or [-128, 127].

Comment: This table will have 40 rows max, thats the reason

Comment: @user2932802 The 40 rows not the reason, but table with million rows that references it, it really reason.

Comment: `TinyInt has a storage of 1 byte, so [0, 255] or [-128, 127]` Can you reference to the documentation?

Comment: @Shishdem - the correct reference for SQL Server compact would be [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424.aspx) - and in all the places, I can find, the range is always given as `0 - 255`, **not** `-128 - 127` as you state in your answer.